# Mac Pro 2013 eGPU

Tags: macbook-pro, mac

My friend has a Late 2013 Mac Pro and he would like to connect an eGPU. I don't know much about Macs. Can someone suggest an eGPU case that would be compatible and a GPU to go into it? I've tried looking online but I've read there's compatibility issues because of Apple dropping support for older hardware.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it is not officially supported by Apple there is a workaround published on egpu.io.

PurgeWrangler
https://egpu.io/forums/mac-setup/script-enable-egpu-on-tb1-2-macs-on-macos-10-13-4/

It is still rather experimental and you should proceed at your own risk at this stage, but there are many who use it and positive reviews about it.

Terminal knowledge is required.

Answer (score 3):

eGPU support is only on new Macs & doesn't stretch back to the current Mac Pro.

> eGPUs are supported on MacBook Pro notebooks released in 2016 and
>   later1, iMac computers introduced in 2017 and later, and iMac Pro.
>   Your Mac must also have macOS High Sierra 10.13.4 installed.

Ref: Apple KB - [Use an external graphics processor with your Mac](https://support.apple.com/HT208544)

Comment: That said, check out the blog on macvidcards.com for more information. Some people have been attempting to do this, I’m not sure how successfully